# Angular and secret keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have been learning angular 2 and have been doing research on how to protect data within my app.

How, if possible, can you obstruct data from the front end of the app? Is it possible to serve the angular app through a node server, say using Universal Angular, which would mean variable values can be hidden from the user on the front end.

I am essentially looking for the solution of hiding private keys which will give the app access to various APIs/creating auth headers/paths. I've read a solution is to have an API bridge for the app - so I would connect to that to retrieve the data/keys - but then how do I protect that from access? Since that endpoint would then be exposed and could be abused, or if getting keys the response is visible. The idea of locking down to domain I have read is unreliable due to spoofing and locking to IP wouldn't work as its front end or through an app?

I feel there is a glaringly obvious answer that I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, when the server sends the data as response to a request, then the data can be accessed from the outside.
If you don't want that, then don't send the data.

You didn't mention what problem you actually try to solve. For API keys you can for example do the request to the API on the server and provide an API on your own server for your clients and then make the server forward the requests to the actual API server.

Comment: Hi Günter, that makes sense - but the that's whats tripping me up about the concept!! Say I want to connect to an API to retrieve some data. That API obviously needs to authentication to get the data, so if I proxy through my own API to it - whats prevents my API endpoint being exposed and people accessing it via that? I've hidden the connection, but left the door open? I then need to authenticate that - but then how do protect it? Seems to be a loop

Comment: That's a difficult question. You want to provide free and easy access for nice people but block bad people. If you find a good solution let me know ;-) What you can do is to use some authentication token and when that was not provided with the request then don't forward the call. This way you don't expose the API to anyone and don't expose the API key at all.

Comment: So could some sort of solution be, as the app loads - do a basic request for the app to get a JWT? Use that to auth against my own API?

Comment: Exactly, if the JWT token sent with the request is valid, forward the request, otherwise return an error code.

Answer (score 3):

You must assume that everything that is held in your frontend *is* visible to anybody that can access your frontend.
All JS variables, storage (local, session), network requests, etc. in your front end are unsecured from users of your frontend.

You can (and should) use SSL to make hide data from anybody in between your server and the browser, but there is just no way to secure data held in your frontend from users of your frontend. (At least if your frontend is available on "regular" browser as opposed to some tightened kiosk mode installations.)